# How do I centre an image that sticks to the bottom of a varying size div?

Tags: html, css

How do I centre an image and make the image sink/stick to the bottom of the div it is contained within?

```
<div class="cover">
    <img class="cover_img" src="img/index/banner_me.png">
</div>

.cover {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 850px;
}

    .cover_img {
        width: 850px;
        height: 660px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

It would be ideal if its possible as a background image to the div but if not an  will be okay. Sorry for my simple question.

Answer (score 2):

```
background-position:center 100%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/Suw4t/

Answer (score 0):

You could also add an empty extra div to contain the background image:

```
<div class="image-center"></div>


.image-center{
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

And then set the desired attributes on that div in your css. Place this div at the end of your content for the image to appear at the bottom of whatever parent container you are in. The margin-left and margin-right will center the image.