# How position my image bottom centered within a div that's already positioned absolute?

Tags: css, html

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="icon" style="height: 85px; position: relative;">
<img src="images/image.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
   .sol-add-section {
            width: 160px; 
            float: left;
            margin: 20px 50px 0px 0px;
    }

     .image { max-width: 160px; 
              max-height:85px;
              position: absolute;
              bottom:5px; 
              margin-left:10px;
    }

    .icon {

    .sol-add-section image {

     display: block;
    }
```

As you can see the div is position: relative and the image is `position: absolute`.

Can I make this image centered without adding `margin-right`, etc. i.e. `margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto` (I've already tried this).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I centre an image that sticks to the bottom of a varying size div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643976/how-do-i-centre-an-image-that-sticks-to-the-bottom-of-a-varying-size-div)

Comment: Is this kind of positioning necessary? (Relative/Absolute)
And if it is, subtract width of the image from width of the div then assign that value to your image(left or right property)

Answer (score 0):

in your css add value

```
.icon .img {
position :relative;
left:(your value);
right:(your value);
top:(your value);
bottom:(your value);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use text-align:center; with:

a) absolute:positionning and a negative margin equal to half width of image:

```
<div class="icon" style="height: 85px; position: relative;text-align:center;background:gray">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/80/people/1" style="position:absolute;bottom:0;margin-left:-50px;   ">
</div>
```

b) in the flow, line-height and vertical-align:

```
<div class="icon" style="height: 85px; line-height:85px;text-align:center;background:gray">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/50/people/1" style="vertical-align:bottom;   ">
</div>
```

see code in action here : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dbmFv

Comment: b goes to my choice, you have as well the option to use background-image if image is only for decoration purpose.